# Custom event handling

Tags: c#, winforms

I have mainVariable.cs that contains delegates for events. Also I have several forms and a worker.cs. My problem is that Login form is starting form and handles some event. After that it hides itself and shows another form. Now the problem starts here, because second form which started after login, cant handle any events. I mean when I raise an event from worker.cs and login form handles the event not the second from even if I dispose the login form. How can I solve this puzzle ?

Comment: please add some code

Comment: wpf? winforms? ??????

Comment: WinForm but I cant share codes, it too big

Comment: _it too big_ - then make the effort to create a new minimal project.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to your Programm.cs

```
        Application.Run(loginForm);
        if (loginForm.IsLoggedIn == true)
        {
            ERS_FDData.ERSUser user = loginForm.user;
            loginForm.Close();
            Application.Run(new frmMain(loginForm.user));
        }
        else
            Application.Exit();
```

After the login is done, you need to set the Mainf Frame to be the application default window

Comment: did you subscribe to the eventhandler anywhere?

Comment: The eventhandler is null if no method is designated as it's eventhandler (No method in the events invocation list)

Comment: Yes I did, at the second form

Answer (score 0):

For any event to be handled you need to assign it a subroutine.

You can do this from any form, given you initialize and show it first.

For example.

```
    Form1
    {
       FormLoad()
       {
           mybutton.click += new EventHandler(myfunction);
       }
       myfunction(object o, EventArgs e) { // Dostuff }
    }
```

So you'd initialize Form1 something like this

```
Form1 myform = new Form1();
```

And the event will work as the form expects.

Comment: I did this but still event handles in the first form because of that second form events not working. It says I'm null.